# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate persistence provider for fetching a number of records from a DB. Here `createQuery` is used to create a query which returns a number of records from the DB, which is identified based on a specific id given by the user (which is the primary key of the corresponding table):

```
WFile wFile = d.getWFile();
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(QUERY_DECISION_ORDINAL);
query.setParameter("id", wFile.getId());
Long count = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
d.setOrdinal(count.intValue());
entityManager.persist(d);
```

My problem is: `getSingleResult` throws an error only for some specific ids and runs smooth for other.

The stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection  
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:131)
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of he exception.